# How to filter sub collection in firebase (flutter)?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called `Channels` and inside it I have a sub collection called `messages`, so I want to filter the channel collection then I want to fetch the messages from it ?

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Channels') >> where(id = user.uid) <<<<< I want to filter this 
        .doc()
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("createdAt")
        .snapshots(),
```

[image: Firebase]

*any help will be appreciated ^^

error :
[image: error message]

The method 'doc' isn't defined for the type 'Query'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'doc'.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) you should use the `where` method. Combine that with [firebase.flutter.dev docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/) (heading with relevant example [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference)), you should be able to accomplish this using something like:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('Channels')
  .where('id', isEqualTo: user.uid)
```

Also is channelID same with senderID? If the answer is yes, do you need both (and are you sure that is the structure you want)? :)

Comment: Yeah but still I cant put the where condition like this : FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Channels').where('')
            .doc() >>> error : The method 'doc' isn't defined for the type 'Query'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'doc'.
            .collection("messages")
            .orderBy("createdAt")
            .snapshots(),

Comment: is `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Channels').where('id', isEqualTo: user.uid).doc().collection("messages")` returning any error?

Comment: I have updated the post you can see what I mean ^^

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `doc()` is empty, so FB does not know which doc to go into.

Just add the id of the channel inside the `doc()`, like so:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('Channels')
  .doc(recieverID)
  .collection('messages')
  .orderBy('createdAt')
```

Comment: as I mentioned before ,, I have a channel collection every channel will have a unique recieverID , so what I want is to fetch the messages from this specific channel and not all the messages inside other channel

Comment: got it. Updating answer now

Answer (score 0):

A Firestore query can only access documents from a single collection, or from a group of collections all with the same name. So you can't filter documents from `messages` based on fields in their parent `Channels` document.

What you **can** do is add the relevant field to each `messages` document, e.g. in a field named `channelUID`. Then you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to query all `messages` collections:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup("messages")
        .orderBy("createdAt")
        .where("channelUID", isEqualTo: user.uid)
        .snapshots(),
```

Comment: the problem is that  the user can make more than one channel every channel has a unique receiverid . if I use your function to query all messages it will be fetch all the messages from all channels here is the function i used to send a message ` void onSend(ChatMessage message) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Channels')
        .doc()
        .collection("messages")
        .doc(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString())
        .set(message.toJson());
    setState(() {
      messages = [...messages, message];
      print(messages.length);
    });`

Comment: The `.where("channelUID", isEqualTo: user.uid)` filters on the UID, same as the query in your question does. The only difference is that you need to add that field to each document in the `messages` subcollections now to allow the use-case. If you still get too many resulting documents, you will have to add more fields to the `messages` documents to allow filtering them too, because Firestore can only access documents from a single collection in a query, or from a group of collections all with the same name.

Comment: OP has their data-structure in place. So changing the database structure is not what is asked for. Your answer is not wrong, if the question was about how it could be restructured